# limit calculation using l'Hopital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

A generalized logarithmic function looks like this:

$$\frac{(1-h)^{1-x}}{1-x}$$

Apparently if you take the limit of $x$ to $1$, the result is $\ln(1-h)$. However, I do not get this result. Somewhere in between u get 0/0, so you apply l'Hopital, and you take the derivative of the nominator and denominator separately, but then I go wrong somewhere...

Comment: Yep, still trying to solve it, answer didn't get me far enough.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$(1-h)^{1-x}=e^{(1-x)\log (1-h)}\implies [(1-h)^{1-x}]'=[e^{(1-x)\log (1-h)}]'=(1-h)^{1-x}\log(1-h)$$

and then by l'Hopital

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(1-h)^{1-x}-1}{ 1-x}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(1-h)^{1-x}\log(1-h)}{ -1}=-\log (1-h)$$

Comment: Thx, but no sorry I don't get it. First of all I get 1/0 instead of 0/0 so I can't even apply l'Hospital it seems. Second of all, if you apply l'Hospital, I don't get your solution for the derivative for the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

We assume $0<h<1$, one may write
$$
(1-h)^{1-x}=e^{(1-x)\ln (1-h)}
$$ giving, by differentiating with respect to $x$
$$
\left((1-h)^{1-x} \right)'=\left(e^{(1-x)\ln (1-h)}\right)'=\ln (1-h)\cdot e^{(1-x)\ln (1-h)}
$$ then by using [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(1-h)^{1-x}}{1-x}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\ln (1-h)\cdot(1-h)^{1-x}}{-1}=\cdots.
$$Hope you can finish it.

Comment: Thx, but no sorry I don't get it. First of all I get 1/0 instead of 0/0 so I can't even apply l'Hospital it seems. Second of all, if you apply l'Hospital, I don't get your solution for the derivative for the denominator.